# How can I find functions with mapping cycles in them?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Im doing some undergrad research in category theory and as a part of this research I will need polynomial functions of a specific sort. I need to find functions that will map f(x) to y, f(y) to z and f(z) to x.  The function I'm looking for could also have a 4 cycle rather than the 3 cycle I just described. 2 cycles are trivial to find.

This function must be a polynomial, must have all integer coefficients, and will preferably have all positive coefficients.

I have reduced this problem to finding integers a, b, and c such that

1. `a` is divisible by `(a-c)(b-c)`
2. `b` is divisible by `(c-a)(b-a)`
3. `c` is divisible by `(a-b)(c-b)`

I'm not sure that this will help, but finding such integers is as good as finding a cubic polynomial with a 3 cycle.

Comment: Have you looked into Lagrange polynomials? You can make them take on any values you like at specified points.

Comment: @TomKern Wow, I didn't know it had a name.  This is essentially what I've been doing.  It is hard to make it come out as a polynomial with integer coefficients AND integer values for the 3 cycle variables.